# Delete a duplicate Record on Save Button of a Form in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to set up a small table and form in Access for some purpose. The table has Four Columns (ID, Name, Date, Amount). The form has all of the table's fields with a save button at the end. Right now it allows for entry of duplicate entries (same Name, Date, Amount). I want to make sure when someone uses the form to make an entry, they can't enter the same Name, Date and Amount twice. So is there a way when someone saves a new record to check if the record exists and then prevent (delete) duplicate entry? I am thinking of some kind of an event that when someone clicks on the Save button. Any code that can do that helps. I have no experience in VB so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The simplest way is to set each field's Indexed property to "Yes (No Duplicates). This way an error message-box is thrown if a value exists. The second approach is through VBA by cancelling the form's auto-update and handling it manually using a Save button, once validation is successful.

Comment: That would not work here because two of the three fields can be the same, but not all of the three fields can be the same.